# The editor has encountered an unexpected error

Tags: wordpress

When custom theme plugin is activated is throwing an error when Im editing post.
Have tried so many things.

I have tried deactivting all others plugin , have installed the classic editor , some scripts that i found in google but none of them is working.

Answer (score 2):

do you have access to `wp-config.php`? If so, try enabling `WP_DEBUG` to true, then go back to editing the post. You should now see errors appearing that can help point you towards a theme file or function that is causing the error.

My answer may sound like the typical "Make sure it's plugged in" question.. But this often helps me troubleshoot issues all the time.

[Here's more information on debugging issues in WP](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).